# PHP API - Encode multiple data entries

Tags: php, json, api

Here is the desired output (in JSON)

```
{
     response: {
       code: "400",
       total_results: "100",
       listings: [
        {
           "title": "My First Application",  
           "imgage": "image1.jpg"

        },

        {
           "title": "My second Application",  
           "imgage": "image1.jpg"

        },  

       ]
     }
}
```

I store the `response` which is given to allow for status codes etc.. and the actual listings is the data. I am building a mobile application so I want to be able to put: `data.title`, `data.image` for example.

Here is what I have so far (in PHP):

```
 $response = array("response" =>
    array(
        "code" => "400",
        "total_results" => "100",

        "listings" => array("title" => "My first listing", "image" => "image1.jpg"),


    ),

  );
```

However this is wrong as it's not allowing me to have multiple listings, nor is it allowing me (inside the app) to reference `title` and `image`.

Can anyone suggest a way how I can do this so that the data is properly formatted correctly?

Comment: `'listings' => array( array('title' => ...), array(...) )`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make your listings a multi-dimensional array:

```
$response = array("response" =>
    array(
        "code" => "400",
        "total_results" => "100",

        "listings" => array(
            (object) ["title" => "My first listing", "image" => "image1.jpg"],
            (object) ["title" => "My second listing", "image" => "image1.jpg"]
        ),


    ),

  );
```

I've cast the arrays in the listings as objects, as that's what your JSON structure suggested they should be.

Comment: FWIW, `json_encode` would encode those arrays to objects even without casting them...

Comment: @deceze Interesting, thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

try to make a class :

`class Item{
       public $title;
       public $image;
       function __construct($title, $img){
          $this->title = $title;
          $this->image = $img;
       }
    }`

So now you can do this :

```
$response = array("response" =>
    array(
        "code" => "400",
        "total_results" => "100",
        "listings" => array(new Item("My first listing","image1.jpg"),new Item("My second listing","image2.jpg"))
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter *how* you decide to do it *(and, as you can see, "there's more than one way to do it ..."),* the bottom line is that you need "an array **of arrays**." (Or, what might be called in some other languages, "an array of `struct`s ...)

JSON will obligingly encode and decode *any* PHP data structure to-and-from a string. "Get the data-structure right," and JSON will take care of itself.

Answer (score -2):

With this array did you try : 
    $json_response = json_encode($response);

Comment: Presumebly, he *did,* but the outcome was not as he expected it to be. Not JSON's fault, though ...